# Imagemagick compose image within transparent part of another image

Tags: batch-file, image-processing

In Imagemagick script how can I resize and insert one picture into the transparent center of PNG file, using the dimensions of the transparent portion of the PNG file as the resize geometry for the first file; effectively resizing the first image INTO the transparent portion of the second image?

I am thinking of using 'Identify' to determine the geometry of the transparent portion and using that as the resize argument, but I don't know if 'Identify' can return the geometry of the transparent portion of a PNG file. The PNG file is a picture of a nice frame with the center transparent.

So Far I have to hard-code the size to match the transparent 'window'...

```
@Echo off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

set Frame="C:\FRAMES\Frame-01-516x384.png"
set Append=-Frame-01
Set window="516x384^!"

FOR %%a in (%*) DO (
    set image=%%a
    set Output="%%~da%%~pa%%~na!Append!%%~xa"
    convert -quiet !Frame! ^( -rotate "90<" -resize !Window! !Image! ^) -gravity center -composite !output!
    )
```